# String[] array variable shows a null value although I am setting a value to it

Tags: java, variables

I have a string variable

```
static String[] genrename;
```

I am assigning values to it in one of my method and then displaying its content.
It does store the value fine. But when I am accessing the String variables directly or from a getter method(). It shows a null value in the string.

Any ideas?

```
public class GenreParsing {
    static int entries;
    static String[] genrecode;
    static String[] genrename;
    public GenreParsing() {
    }
    public void parsing(String returnContent) {
        try {
            JSONObject jo_genres = new JSONObject(returnContent);
            System.out.println(jo_genres);
            JSONArray ja_genres = jo_genres.getJSONArray("genres");
            System.out.println(ja_genres);
            entries=ja_genres.length();
            for (int i = 1; i < entries; i++) {
                JSONObject jo_genre = (JSONObject) ja_genres.get(i);
                JSONArray ja_genre = jo_genre.getJSONArray("genre");
                JSONObject genreinfo = (JSONObject) ja_genre.get(0);
                genrecode = new String[entries];
                genrename = new String[entries];
                genrecode[i] = genreinfo.getString("code");
                genrename[i] = genreinfo.getString("name");
                System.out.println(genrecode[i]);
                System.out.println(genrename[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
    public int no_of_entries() {
        System.out.println(entries);
        return entries;
    }
    public String getgenrecode(int x) {
        System.out.print(genrecode[x]);
        return genrecode[x];
    }
    public String getgenrename(int y) {
        return genrename[y];
    }
}
```

Comment: It is much easier if you show us the code.

Comment: There's a bug in your code. That's all we can say without looking at it.

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: You've clearly not understood what new `new String[entries]` actually does. Also, you seem to be confused about proper use of `static`. Peter Lang and Thomas Jung are pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comments and the answers. It helped.

Comment: @bendin, I'm all for fixing "fugly" code (as you so eloquently put it) but *not* when that changes the actual meaning of the code. The removal of the empty constructor and print statements should not have been done (in my opinion) - I've put them back and beautified the code *without* changing its nature.

Comment: @paxdiablo: removal of empty constructor doesn't change the code, as java compiler will generate one for you if there is no constructor left.

Comment: My opinion is that beautifying code should be restricted to formatting. You never know whether there may be some other problem buried in the unnecessary code (not so in that case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing `genrecode=new String[entries];` and `genrename=new String[entries];` *inside* the loop? This creates a new string array every single time through the loop, invalidating the previous assignments.

Try this instead:

```
genrecode=new String[entries];
genrename=new String[entries];
for(int i = 0; i < entries; i++) {
    JSONObject jo_genre = (JSONObject) ja_genres.get(i);
    JSONArray ja_genre=jo_genre.getJSONArray("genre");
    JSONObject genreinfo = (JSONObject) ja_genre.get(0);
    genrecode[i]= genreinfo.getString("code");
    genrename[i] = genreinfo.getString("name");
    System.out.println(genrecode[i]);
    System.out.println(genrename[i]);
}
```

It creates a big-enough array up front and populates all the array elements. I've also changed the starting value for `i` in the above code because array indexes usually start at zero, not one. You may want to check that.

One final thing to watch out for is those statics. If your class is ever allocated as multiple instances, they may overwrite each other's data in that case (especially in a threaded program where you can't dictate sequencing easily). Making these private to an instance will prevent this.

Again, it depends on how you're using the class. If it's a singleton, it won't matter (yet), but I tend to plan ahead - you don't know when you may want to change it to a non-singleton and you lose nothing (in my opinion) using instance variables even for a singleton.

Answer (score 3):

You're overwriting your array again and again by doing

```
genrecode=new String[entries];
genrename=new String[entries];
```

in the loop. Put this before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should make all fields instance variables so multiple instances won't interfere.

```
public class GenreParsing {
 private int entries;
 private String[] genrecode;
 private String[] genrename;
}
```

Additionally it is always good style to ensure proper encapsulation by restricting the access to internal state of a class.

You should consider following the [Java Coding conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConvTOC.doc.html) and handling the exceptions thrown properly.

Answer (score 0):

maybe `string[n]` item is `null`, not the array itself.

Comment: No it outputs the value while I do 
System.out.println(genrecode[i]);
inside the method where I save the data in the string

Comment: maybe your value somehow goes out of scope when you leave the method.

Comment: You mention `genrecode[i]` here but `genrename[]` in your question. Could this be related to your problem?

Comment: no that was a sample. I have posted the detailed code. Just ignore the JSON part as I m gettin data for it frm some other class.